# Android dynamic link doesn't survive fresh app installation

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to implement referral in my app with Firebase Dynamic link.

The happy path would be:

1. Link is shared with a JWT token as parameter
2. Another user clicks on the link, doesn't have the app so it goes to the Playstore
3. After app was installed, at app startup, the JWT token is retrieved trough parameters and stored locally
4. New signup is complete, the token is sent to the backend to activate referrer's reward

Problem is that in this scenario, step 3 doesn't find any data at first app startup, whereas it is found when I click on the link anew after the app has been installed.

**This is the way the link is generated for the referrer:**

```
val parameters = new DynamicLink.SocialMetaTagParameters.Builder()
                .setImageUrl(...)
                .setTitle(...)
                .build();

val link = Uri.parse("https://my.domain.com/path/?token=${jwtToken}");

val dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
                .setLink(link)
                .setSocialMetaTagParameters(parameters)
                .setDomainUriPrefix("https://my.domain.com")
                .setAndroidParameters(DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder().build()))
                .setIosParameters(...) 
                .setNavigationInfoParameters(
                       DynamicLink.NavigationInfoParameters.Builder()
                           .setForcedRedirectEnabled(true)
                           .build
                 ).buildDynamicLink()
```

The link is shorten by:

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
                .setDomainUriPrefix("https://my.domain.com/")
                .setLongLink(dynamicLink.getUri())
                .buildShortDynamicLink()
                .addOnCompleteListener(activity, task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                        linkCallback.success(task.getResult().getShortLink().toString());
                    } else {
                        linkCallback.failure(task.getException());
                    }
                })
```

**At app's opening, link is read in the onResume() method of the starting activity :**

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent()) // getIntent() refers to the Activity's method
            .addOnSuccessListener(activity) { data -> // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
   
                val isReferralLink = data?.link?.toString()?.startsWith("https://my.domain.com/path") == true
                val jwt = data?.link?.getQueryParameter("token")

                // Here, data is null. <-------

               // Other attempt :
                data?.let { aiData ->
                    FirebaseAppInvite.getInvitation(aiData)?.let { result ->
                        // Here result is still null
                    }
                }
            } 
}
```

I've seen on a stack overflow thread that it doesn't survive to beta track install, so I tried to leave the beta and use remote config to hide it in production track, but I have not been able see any difference.

And the version I'm using is :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:21.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:17.0.0'
```

**Question:**
Is there something I'm missing here ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

**EDIT:**

In this scenario the link and token are correctly found.

1. Link is shared with a JWT token as parameter
2. Another user clicks on the link, doesn't have the app so it goes to the Playstore
3. After app was installed, the second user clicks again on the link and opens the app for the first time

Comment: and what is in `data?.link` when after `var isReferralLink ...`

Comment: Sorry I just tested it anew, and data is actually null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a few days of testing and researches, I found out why it was not working.

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(activity) { data -> 
                 // Some data reading
            }
```

In this case I was using the addOnSuccessListener() with an activity as parameter, which makes it lifecycle aware. In my app, a new user (fresh install) will be redirected to an onboarding activity, so the listener's activity is paused, and the callback is never fired.

**=> TLDR: Removing this activity parameter solved my problem.**

Comment: I have used the same thing and it is still causing null

Comment: @TejasSherdiwala Did you check your assetlinks.json as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive#app_links)? This was another problem in my case.

Comment: I had a different issue lingering in the code. There was another piece of code which was trying to extract the dynamic link before the logic which I was putting in. Hence the pending dynamic link intent always returned null as there was nothing pending as such.